# How to Troubleshoot Emacs?

Tags: performance, slime, profiler, frozen-emacs

These two questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568150/tips-for-profiling-misbehaving-emacs-lisp) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087532/troubleshooting-techniques-for-emacs-and-emacs-lisp?rq=3) provide some tools to profile and debug emacs. But it doesn't explain exactly how to use those tools to figure out a problem with emacs.

Once you have the profiling reports, what do we do to discover/fix the issue?

In particular, I'm trying to figure out why emacs starts freezing. It doesn't happen right away, but after some use, it starts freezing, and then almost any writing in any buffer (REPL or files) will cause emacs to freeze.

I can recover emacs with `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs` from the terminal, however `C-g` doesn't work.

I can do profiling, but then what?

Here are the profiler reports expanded:

Memory Report

```
    771,470,029  98% - redisplay_internal (C function)
    771,394,545  98%  - eval
    771,390,321  98%   - slime-modeline-string
    771,390,321  98%    - let
    771,390,321  98%     - if
    771,390,321  98%      - let
    771,343,106  98%       - funcall
    771,343,106  98%        - #<lambda 0x1877b54bb09f657>
    771,343,106  98%         - let*
    771,343,106  98%          - slime-presentation-bounds
    771,343,106  98%           - let*
    771,343,106  98%            - progn
    771,343,106  98%             - let*
    771,343,106  98%              - slime-presentation-start
    771,343,106  98%               - let*
    771,343,106  98%                - progn
    771,343,106  98%                 - catch
    771,343,106  98%                  - let*
    771,343,106  98%                   - while
    771,343,106  98%                    - let
    572,874,932  73%                     - previous-single-property-change
    572,874,932  73%                      - debug
    558,755,334  71%                       - recursive-edit
    362,958,557  46%                        - command-execute
    362,958,304  46%                         - call-interactively
    195,863,077  25%                          - byte-code
    195,863,077  25%                           - read--expression
    195,835,338  25%                            + read-from-minibuffer
    167,093,860  21%                          - completing-read-default
    167,093,860  21%                           - apply
    167,093,860  21%                            - vertico--advice
    167,093,860  21%                             - apply
    167,093,860  21%                              - #<compiled -0x4ab4c1268bcabe7>
    166,087,376  21%                               - read-from-minibuffer
        645,659   0%                                + vertico--exhibit
         24,144   0%                                + redisplay_internal (C function)
          4,224   0%                                + timer-event-handler
          4,144   0%                                + marginalia--minibuffer-setup
          1,240   0%                                + minibuffer-setup
          1,136   0%                                + command-execute
          1,056   0%                                + minibuffer-mode
          1,056   0%                                  minibuffer-history-isearch-setup
          1,056   0%                                + frame-windows-min-size
          1,351   0%                          + format-prompt
         14,784   0%                        + redisplay_internal (C function)
          7,552   0%                        + #<compiled -0x1d53ebbb44db555a>
          3,168   0%                        + timer-event-handler
          1,077   0%                        + help-command-error-confusable-suggestions
     11,193,441   1%                       + debugger-setup-buffer
      1,459,351   0%                       + pop-to-buffer
        866,713   0%                       + #<compiled 0x14021c254368a9f8>
        486,985   0%                       + window-resize
    198,468,174  25%                     - debug
    195,846,052  25%                      - recursive-edit
         50,470   0%                       + redisplay_internal (C function)
         17,040   0%                       + timer-event-handler
          1,323   0%                       + command-execute
      1,018,243   0%                      + pop-to-buffer
        830,809   0%                        #<compiled 0xc1a42b78908a9f8>
        679,802   0%                      + debugger-setup-buffer
         30,656   0%       + concat
         16,559   0%       + slime-current-package
          4,224   0%     if
         51,804   0%  + jit-lock-function
          9,408   0%    file-remote-p
          7,936   0%  + menu-bar-update-buffers
          4,224   0%  + which-key--hide-popup-on-frame-size-change
          1,056   0%  + desktop-auto-save-set-timer
      7,029,715   0% + command-execute
      1,260,315   0% + timer-event-handler
         13,648   0% + #<compiled -0x1d53ebbb44db555a>
          1,104   0% + eldoc-schedule-timer
            373   0%   normal-top-level
            160   0% + flycheck-maybe-display-error-at-point-soon
             96   0% + company-post-command
              0   0%   ...
```

CPU Report

```
        3231  91% - ...
        3111  88%  - let*
        3111  88%   - slime-presentation-bounds
        3111  88%    - let*
        3111  88%     - progn
        3005  85%      - let
        3005  85%       - while
        3005  85%        - let
        3005  85%         - funcall
        3005  85%          - #<lambda 0x1877b54bb09f657>
        3005  85%           - let*
        3005  85%            - slime-presentation-bounds
        3005  85%             - let*
        3005  85%              - progn
        3005  85%               - let*
        3005  85%                - slime-presentation-start
        3005  85%                 - let*
        3005  85%                  - progn
        3005  85%                   - catch
        3005  85%                    - let*
        2883  81%                     - while
        1677  47%                      - let
         366  10%                         setq
         146   4%                       + previous-single-property-change
         117   3%                       + debug
         531  15%                      - not
         233   6%                       + slime-presentation-start-p
         106   2%      + let*
         111   3%    Automatic GC
           9   0%  + #<compiled -0x15f50afa8483605a>
         260   7% + command-execute
          41   1% + timer-event-handler
           1   0%   normal-top-level
           1   0% + redisplay_internal (C function)
```

Here is the backtrace from emacs when it freezes:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  (while (not (slime-presentation-start-p this-presentation)) (let ((change-point (previous-single-property-change point presentation object (point-min)))) (if change-point nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values (cond ((bufferp object) (save-current-buffer ... 1)) ((stringp object) 0) ((error "cl-etypecase failed: %s, %s" object ...) nil)) nil))) (setq this-presentation (get-text-property change-point presentation object)) (if this-presentation nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values point nil))) (setq point change-point)))
  (let* ((this-presentation (get-text-property point presentation object))) (while (not (slime-presentation-start-p this-presentation)) (let ((change-point (previous-single-property-change point presentation object (point-min)))) (if change-point nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values (cond (... ...) (... 0) (... nil)) nil))) (setq this-presentation (get-text-property change-point presentation object)) (if this-presentation nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values point nil))) (setq point change-point))) (cl-values point t))
  (catch '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (let* ((this-presentation (get-text-property point presentation object))) (while (not (slime-presentation-start-p this-presentation)) (let ((change-point (previous-single-property-change point presentation object (point-min)))) (if change-point nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values (cond ... ... ...) nil))) (setq this-presentation (get-text-property change-point presentation object)) (if this-presentation nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values point nil))) (setq point change-point))) (cl-values point t)))
  (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-presentation-start (+ 3 (length --cl-rest--))))) (catch '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (let* ((this-presentation (get-text-property point presentation object))) (while (not (slime-presentation-start-p this-presentation)) (let ((change-point (previous-single-property-change point presentation object ...))) (if change-point nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values ... nil))) (setq this-presentation (get-text-property change-point presentation object)) (if this-presentation nil (throw '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (cl-values point nil))) (setq point change-point))) (cl-values point t))))
  (let* ((object (if --cl-rest-- (car-safe (prog1 --cl-rest-- (setq --cl-rest-- (cdr --cl-rest--)))) (current-buffer)))) (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-presentation-start (+ 3 (length --cl-rest--))))) (catch '--cl-block-slime-presentation-start-- (let* ((this-presentation (get-text-property point presentation object))) (while (not (slime-presentation-start-p this-presentation)) (let ((change-point ...)) (if change-point nil (throw ... ...)) (setq this-presentation (get-text-property change-point presentation object)) (if this-presentation nil (throw ... ...)) (setq point change-point))) (cl-values point t)))))
  slime-presentation-start(1 #s(slime-presentation :text "\"SELECT user.id AS t1.id,\n user.name AS t1.name,\n ..." :id 6) #<buffer  *company-sps*>)
  (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-start point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-start (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-end point presentation object)) (end (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-end (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (cl-values start end (and good-start good-end (slime-presentation-whole-p presentation start end object)))))
  (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-presentation-bounds (+ 3 (length --cl-rest--))))) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-start point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-start (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-end point presentation object)) (end (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-end (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (cl-values start end (and good-start good-end (slime-presentation-whole-p presentation start end object))))))
  (let* ((object (if --cl-rest-- (car-safe (prog1 --cl-rest-- (setq --cl-rest-- (cdr --cl-rest--)))) (current-buffer)))) (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-presentation-bounds (+ 3 (length --cl-rest--))))) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-start point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-start (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-end point presentation object)) (end (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (good-end (nth 1 --cl-var--))) (cl-values start end (and good-start good-end (slime-presentation-whole-p presentation start end object)))))))
  slime-presentation-bounds(1 #s(slime-presentation :text "\"SELECT user.id AS t1.id,\n user.name AS t1.name,\n ..." :id 6) #<buffer  *company-sps*>)
  (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-bounds point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (end (nth 1 --cl-var--)) (whole-p (nth 2 --cl-var--))) (funcall function presentation start end whole-p))
  (lambda (presentation point) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-bounds point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (end (nth 1 --cl-var--)) (whole-p (nth 2 --cl-var--))) (funcall function presentation start end whole-p)))(#s(slime-presentation :text "\"SELECT user.id AS t1.id,\n user.name AS t1.name,\n ..." :id 6) 1)
  funcall((lambda (presentation point) (let* ((--cl-var-- (slime-presentation-bounds point presentation object)) (start (nth 0 --cl-var--)) (end (nth 1 --cl-var--)) (whole-p (nth 2 --cl-var--))) (funcall function presentation start end whole-p))) #s(slime-presentation :text "\"SELECT user.id AS t1.id,\n user.name AS t1.name,\n ..." :id 6) 1)
  (let ((presentation (car tail))) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail)))
  (while tail (let ((presentation (car tail))) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail))))
  (let ((tail (slime-presentations-around-point from object))) (while tail (let ((presentation (car tail))) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail)))))
  (progn (let ((tail (slime-presentations-around-point from object))) (while tail (let ((presentation (car tail))) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail))))) (let ((point from)) (while (< point to) (setq point (next-single-property-change point 'slime-repl-presentation object to)) (let* ((presentation (get-text-property point 'slime-repl-presentation object)) (status (get-text-property point presentation object))) (if (slime-presentation-start-p status) (progn (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation point)))))))
  (let* ((--cl-handle-presentation-- #'(lambda (presentation point) (let* ((--cl-var-- ...) (start ...) (end ...) (whole-p ...)) (funcall function presentation start end whole-p))))) (progn (let ((tail (slime-presentations-around-point from object))) (while tail (let ((presentation (car tail))) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail))))) (let ((point from)) (while (< point to) (setq point (next-single-property-change point 'slime-repl-presentation object to)) (let* ((presentation (get-text-property point ... object)) (status (get-text-property point presentation object))) (if (slime-presentation-start-p status) (progn (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation point))))))))
  (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-for-each-presentation-in-region (+ 4 (length --cl-rest--))))) (let* ((--cl-handle-presentation-- #'(lambda (presentation point) (let* (... ... ... ...) (funcall function presentation start end whole-p))))) (progn (let ((tail (slime-presentations-around-point from object))) (while tail (let ((presentation ...)) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail (cdr tail))))) (let ((point from)) (while (< point to) (setq point (next-single-property-change point 'slime-repl-presentation object to)) (let* ((presentation ...) (status ...)) (if (slime-presentation-start-p status) (progn ...))))))))
  (let* ((object (if --cl-rest-- (car-safe (prog1 --cl-rest-- (setq --cl-rest-- (cdr --cl-rest--)))) (current-buffer)))) (progn (if --cl-rest-- (signal 'wrong-number-of-arguments (list 'slime-for-each-presentation-in-region (+ 4 (length --cl-rest--))))) (let* ((--cl-handle-presentation-- #'(lambda (presentation point) (let* ... ...)))) (progn (let ((tail (slime-presentations-around-point from object))) (while tail (let (...) (funcall --cl-handle-presentation-- presentation from) (setq tail ...)))) (let ((point from)) (while (< point to) (setq point (next-single-property-change point ... object to)) (let* (... ...) (if ... ...))))))))
  slime-for-each-presentation-in-region(1 25 (lambda (presentation from to whole-p) (cond (whole-p (slime-ensure-presentation-overlay from to presentation)) ((not undo-in-progress) (slime-remove-presentation-properties from to presentation) (setq any-change t)))))
  (let ((real-start (max 1 (1- start))) (real-end (min (1+ (buffer-size)) (1+ end))) (any-change nil)) (slime-for-each-presentation-in-region real-start real-end #'(lambda (presentation from to whole-p) (cond (whole-p (slime-ensure-presentation-overlay from to presentation)) ((not undo-in-progress) (slime-remove-presentation-properties from to presentation) (setq any-change t))))) (if any-change (progn (undo-boundary))))
  (let ((inhibit-modification-hooks t)) (let ((real-start (max 1 (1- start))) (real-end (min (1+ (buffer-size)) (1+ end))) (any-change nil)) (slime-for-each-presentation-in-region real-start real-end #'(lambda (presentation from to whole-p) (cond (whole-p (slime-ensure-presentation-overlay from to presentation)) ((not undo-in-progress) (slime-remove-presentation-properties from to presentation) (setq any-change t))))) (if any-change (progn (undo-boundary)))))
  slime-after-change-function(1 25)
  company-safe-pixel-substring(#(" user.email AS t1.em..." 0 24 (... :interior syntax-table #^[nil #^[nil #^[nil #^[... nil syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 128 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... 
#^^[3 640 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... 
#^^[3 896 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... 
#^^[3 1408 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[2 4096 ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 4864 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 6144 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ...] #^^[2 8192 
#^^[3 8192 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8320 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8448 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8576 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 8960 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9088 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9216 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9344 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9472 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9600 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9728 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... 
#^^[3 9984 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 10112 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ...] #^^[2 12288 
#^^[3 12288 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 12416 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 12800 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 13184 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... #^^[2 40960 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... #^^[2 61440 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]] #^^[1 65536 ... #^^[2 69632 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 71168 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... #^^[2 126976 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] syntax-table nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 128 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] insert-behind-hooks ... insert-in-front-hooks ... modification-hooks ... rear-nonsticky t face slime-repl-result-face)) 37)
  company-modify-line(#(" user.email AS t1.em..." 0 24 (... :interior syntax-table #^[nil #^[nil #^[nil #^[... nil syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 128 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... 
#^^[3 640 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... 
#^^[3 896 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... 
#^^[3 1408 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[2 4096 ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 4864 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 6144 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ...] #^^[2 8192 
#^^[3 8192 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8320 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8448 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 8576 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 8960 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9088 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9216 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9344 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9472 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9600 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 9728 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... 
#^^[3 9984 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 10112 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ...] #^^[2 12288 
#^^[3 12288 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 12416 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 12800 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... 
#^^[3 13184 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... #^^[2 40960 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... #^^[2 61440 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]] #^^[1 65536 ... #^^[2 69632 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
#^^[3 71168 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... #^^[2 126976 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]] ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] syntax-table nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...] 
#^^[3 128 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] syntax-table 
#^^[3 0 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] #^^[1 0 #^^[2 0 
#^^[3 0 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil] nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ...] insert-behind-hooks ... insert-in-front-hooks ... modification-hooks ... rear-nonsticky t face slime-repl-result-face)) #(" for           1 " 0 1 (mouse-face ... face ...) 1 4 (mouse-face ... face ...) 4 14 (mouse-face ... face ...) 14 16 (face ... mouse-face ...) 16 17 (mouse-face ... face ...)) 20)
  company--replacement-string((... ... ... ...) 1 (... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...) 21 nil t)
  apply(company--replacement-string (... ... ... ...) 1 (... 21 nil t))
  company-pseudo-tooltip-show(45 21 0)
  company-pseudo-tooltip-show-at-point(1954 3)
  company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend(post-command)
  company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend(post-command)
  company-call-frontends(post-command)
  company-post-command()
  company-idle-begin(#<buffer *slime-repl qlot*> #<window 6 on *slime-repl qlot*> 356 1954)
  apply(company-idle-begin (#<buffer *slime-repl qlot*> #<window 6 on *slime-repl qlot*> 356 1954))
  timer-event-handler([t 26029 6083 922890 nil company-idle-begin (#<buffer *slime-repl qlot*> #<window 6 on *slime-repl qlot*> 356 1954) nil 0 nil])
```

Comment: Profiling is not particularly useful for diagnosing hangs. See if you can get a useful backtrace by turning on `debug-on-event` and then doing the `SIGUSR2` thing when it hangs. The default value of `debug-on-event` seems to be `sigusr2` but check to make sure that yours is set to that value. If it *is* set to that value, did you get a backtrace when you sent the SIGUSR2? If so, add it to the question.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, I couldn't find the debug-on-event on `M-x`, but they backtrace was opening anyway and I just posted it. Does that help at all?

Comment: `debug-on-event` is a variable, not a function. Check it with `C-h v debug-on-event` but since you got a backtrace when you sent a SIGUSR2 to emacs, it's most probably already set to ``sigusr2` (which is the default value). I'll take a look at the backtrace later.

Comment: @NickD Thanks! I appreciate it... I see a lot of `slime-presentation` related functions being called. Could it be related to that?

Comment: I haven't had time to look and I know very little  about `slime` or `slime-presentation` or `company` to say anything of value. It could be related to any one (or more) of these, but it also could be something completely  different. If similar backtraces occur on multiple hangs, then that would tie the hang more firmly to these three, but even then we'd need to go through the code to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think the backtraces are all similar. When you say code do you mean the code printed in the backtrace or do you mean reading the source for the `slime-presentation`* functions?

Comment: Yes, and also for `company` and that timer that starts the ball rolling (at the bottom of the backtrace). If all the backtraces look similar, then that pretty much narrows down the suspects to what is shown on the backtrace: every time you get a hang and the backtrace looks similar to what you show above is another data point that one or more of these pieces of code is responsible for it, so the probability that something *else* is causing it gets smaller and smaller. Certainty is always elusive, but certainty within reasonable bounds can be achieved this way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. hm, so what should I do? remove company from my init file?

Comment: I just disabled global-company-mode and emacs stopped freezing. Thank you! Now the question is why it's happening? I'm not really doing anything special in my init file besides consult-company and some simple customization, I even had removed the slime-company package from init.

Comment: Well, that''s excellent progress! I would start by running `company-idle-init` by hand and see if I could reproduce the hang that way. That may be a long, frustrating and ultimately fruitless effort, but a lot of debugging is that way. If you *can* reproduce the hang, then you could try instrumenting some of the functions with `edebug` and single stepping through them until you pinpoint the source of the hang exactly. That's going to be even more frustrating, so you might want to open an issue at the appropriate site (maybe the `company` site on Github?) asking for help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, you basically answered the question in your comments. If you copy paste your comments into an answer I can accept it for future people who read this. Thanks again! I really appreciate the guidance :)

Comment: I'll try but I'm sick currently so it's going to take a little time.

Comment: oy, feel better soon